# Trying to get PHPMyAdmin setup and working

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have installed PHPMyAdmin, and now it's located at `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` - in fact I believe `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php` runs it.

I want to run it - which I'm guessing has to be through a web browser. I've linked to it from a public PHP file:

```
include('../../../usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php')
```

...and it's not really working properly (when clicking links they don't work etc.) I can provide more info on errors but I'm guessing it's obvious it wouldn't work.

How do I get this working?

Comment: why not try accessing it through http://localhost/phpmyadmin ?

Comment: That does nothing. Safari can't connect to the server

Comment: How did you install it, then?

Comment: Uploading it to my server

Comment: does typing http://localhost/ work in your browser ? If not apache is not running

Comment: localhost = Safari can't connect to server. I'm using a remote server for this

Comment: Hay, I think you need to reconfigure phpmyadmin. I don't how to configure on MAC. But, I know on Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS